# POST the same UUID into two tables with Node / PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to make a POST request that will insert the same UUID value into two tables: 'employee' and 'skill'. I have tried this a few different ways, but have not been able to do so. Here is my query for posting the UUID (and a 'summary') into one table:

```
app.post("/employees/:id/skills", async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const { summary } = req.body;
    const addEmployeeSkill = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO skill(skill_uuid, summary)VALUES(uuid_generate_v4(), $1) RETURNING *",
      [summary],
    );
    res.json(addEmployeeSkill.rows[0]);   
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

My question is: how do I get the same UUID that is being generated into the 'skill' table to also insert into the skill_uuid column of the 'employee' table?

Comment: generate a UUID on nodejs side instead of using `uuid_generate_v4`. Then run 2 queries in a transaction.

Comment: Does the row in the `employee` table already exist, i.e. do you want to update an existing employee after that?

Comment: I'm creating a new employee with a different post request. Then I want to add a skill to that employee based on the employee's uuid, which is the ":id" part of the endpoint in the above "/employees/:id/skills"